# How to remove space between graph and caption in Latex?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=15cm, height=20cm]{Figures/MapSamplePolyGoogle.pdf}
\decoRule
%\vspace{-1cm}
\caption[Map of the stratum 6' sample]{Residential condominium properties in stratum 6 Sample in Bogota, Sample by neighborhood}
\label{fig:MapE6}
\end{figure}
```

The packages that I use are:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

I am using the template https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis
Masters/Doctoral Thesis
LaTeX Template
Version 2.5 (27/8/17)

I obtain this

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you a) make a [mre] and b) make sure that the excessive white space is not simply part of your image

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are right. I changed the plot size in R then it works in Latex